# How can i call a second service from the result of a different service call in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following

```
    $scope.submitData = function () 
    {
       myService.getdatabaseObjects({
            Field1: $scope.field1,                
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.data !== null && result.data !== '') 
            {                                   
                if (result.data.hasobjects.length === 0)
                    $scope.msg = 'There are No Objects,Are you sure you want to submit ?';
                else
                    $scope.msg = 'Are you sure you want to submit ?';
            }

            // should the call to mydialogModal go in here ?

        });

        // I want to set the $scope.msg depending on the result from above ?

        mydialogModal($scope.msg, 'Yes', 'No')
            .result.then(function (result) {                   
                $scope.gridLinkedMapsData.sync();
                myService.submitrego({
                    Field1: $scope.field1,
                }).then(function (result) {                        
                    if (!result.data.success) 
                    {
                        mydialogModal(result.data.error, 'Submit error', 'OK',    false);                        
                    }                        
                });
            });
    };
```

I want to set the $scope.msg on my dialog depending on the result of $scope.mappingdata.hasobjects.length. If the length is > 0 then it is 'There are No Objects,Are you sure you want to submit ?' else the other. But what seems to happen is that the second service gets called without waiting for the first to complete
Should I be putting the second service call in the .then of the first ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your guess is correct, the second call does not wait the first one to return, because of the **asynchronous nature of Javascript**. Put the modal code into a function and call it into `then`:

```
$scope.submitData = function () 
{
   myService.getdatabaseObjects({
        Field1: $scope.field1,                
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.data !== null && result.data !== '') 
        {                                   
            if (result.data.hasobjects.length === 0)
                $scope.msg = 'There are No Objects,Are you sure you want to submit ?';
            else
                $scope.msg = 'Are you sure you want to submit ?';

             $scope.openModal();
        }

    });

};

$scope.openModal = function() {
    mydialogModal($scope.msg, 'Yes', 'No')
        .result.then(function (result) {                   
            $scope.gridLinkedMapsData.sync();
            myService.submitrego({
                Field1: $scope.field1,
            }).then(function (result) {                        
                if (!result.data.success) 
                {
                    mydialogModal(result.data.error, 'Submit error', 'OK',    false);                        
                }                        
            });
        });
}
```